# Using toChar to convert W3C XML Schema xs:dateTime type format to dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to convert an XML Schema xs:dateTime formatted date to a more readable format using `to_char`.

I've tried:

```
select to_char('2013-08-16T09:55:02+02:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss') 
  from dual;
```

but this fails.

Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: Isn't better to do "select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') 
from dual;" right away? (reacting to your previous question)

Comment: No. Two separate occurrences. One is the data being sent as part of a web service. This is to format the data that is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string literal to the time stamp with time zone data type by using `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()` and then apply `TO_CHAR()` function:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz( '2013-08-16T09:55:02+02:00'
                              , 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mi:ssx TZH:TZM'
                               )
               , 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss') as res                 
  from dual
```

Result:

```
Res:
-----------------
16-08-2013 09:55:02
```

Comment: This gives the error: ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12

Comment: to_char(to_timestamp_tz(xtab.created,'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssx TZH:TZM'),'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss') is what was need because the hh is in 24 hour format.

Comment: If I get the error ORA-01874: time zone hour must be between -12 and 14 how do I fix this?

Comment: This error occurs when your system is using 12-hour format and a string literal you are trying to convert is 24-hour format. So check your `nls_timezone_tz_format` settings and use appropriate time format mask.